# SonarQube bulk update gives error 502

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

We have several customer projects hosted on our sonarqube instance and couple of project teams reported issues while using bulk update feature. When tried to update 10+ issues for 2+ fields they get a 502 issue. I tried this on our dev instance and faced the same issue. IIS\Sonar\Web logs do not show any error.

Has someone seen this error? Can someone let me know what could be going wrong.

FYI, we do not have a proxy server hop for our dev instance so when a request is made the request is directly sent to the server hosting sonarqube instance whereas the production instance has a proxy server configured.

SonarQube Version : 6.1

Please let me know if any further clarification would be needed on the question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of SonarQube.

Comment: Updated with SonarQube version 6.1@G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam